# Why are some functions within a namespace accessible without the namespace scoping prefix?

Tags: c++

Shouldn't functions within a namespace only be accessible via using the namespace scoping or by the using directive?

I am having a problem where certain functions, defined inside of a namespace, are accessible OUTSIDE of that namespace.  I believe there should be a compiler error, but I am not getting one across the three different compilers I have tried (VS.NET 2003, VS2010 and GCC 4).

Here is the code:

```
namespace N{
  typedef struct _some_type *some_type;
  struct some_struct { int x; };
  void A(void);
  void B(int);
  void C(some_type*);
  void D(some_type);
  void E(struct some_struct);
}

using N::some_type;
using N::some_struct;

void TestFunction()
{
  some_type foo;
  some_struct s;

  N::A();         //should compile (and does on VS2003, VS2010, and GCC 4.1.2)
  ::A();          //shouldn't compile (and doesn't on VS2003, VS2010, and GCC 4.1.2)
  A();            //shouldn't compile (and doesn't on VS2003, VS2010, and GCC 4.1.2)

  N::B(0);        //should compile (and does on VS2003, VS2010, and GCC 4.1.2)
  ::B(0);         //shouldn't compile (and doesn't on VS2003, VS2010, and GCC 4.1.2)
  B(0);           //shouldn't compile (and doesn't on VS2003, VS2010, and GCC 4.1.2)

  N::C(&foo);     //should compile (and does on VS2003, VS2010, and GCC 4.1.2)
  ::C(&foo);      //shouldn't compile (and doesn't on VS2003, VS2010, and GCC 4.1.2)
  C(&foo);        //shouldn't compile (but does on VS2003, VS2010, and GCC 4.1.2) -- problem!

  N::D(foo);      //should compile (and does on VS2003, VS2010, and GCC 4.1.2)
  ::D(foo);       //shouldn't compile (and doesn't on VS2003, VS2010, and GCC 4.1.2)
  D(foo);         //shouldn't compile (but does on VS2003, VS2010, and GCC 4.1.2) -- problem!

  N::E(s);        //should compile (and does on VS2003, VS2010, and GCC 4.1.2)
  ::E(s);         //shouldn't compile (and doesn't on VS2003, VS2010, and GCC 4.1.2)
  E(s);           //shouldn't compile (but does on VS2003, VS2010, and GCC 4.1.2) -- problem!
}
```

None of the functions should be accessible without using the N:: prefix, but C, D, and E are for some unknown reason.  I initially thought it was a compiler bug, but because I am seeing this across multiple compilers it makes me question what is going on.

Comment: I thought this was an "old-compiler bug", but that also compiles on gcc 4.6.

Comment: My best guess is the fact that you have these lines: `using N::some_type;` and `using N::some_struct;` and the return types of C, D, and E are those types.

Comment: Greg, you can remove the usings and it still happens.  Also the return types of all of the functions are void.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you're seeing the effect of [Koenig lookup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup).  In your example, `foo` and `s` are types
defined in namespace `N`.  Your calls to routines `C`, `D`, and `E` use arguments of those types,  so namespace `N` is searched in order to resolve those function calls.

Comment: Side note: Adding parentheses, i.e. `(C)(&foo)` will prevent argument-dependent lookup.

Comment: Well, you are correct.  It is in section 3.4.2 of the 2003 C++ spec.  I happen to disagree with this part of the spec and think it was ill-conceived, but there it is.  Does anyone know if there is a way to force a more strict namespace scoping in GCC or VC++?

Comment: @syplex In fact it's extremely useful for properly looking up free-functions based on the argument types inside templates. I don't think g++ offers such an option as it would go against what's required by the standard. What's the *real* problem you're trying to solve here?

Comment: @Mark B I don't see why you couldn't properly scope the namespace in that case or include a using directive.

Comment: @Jesse Good, thanks but unfortunately adding parens doesn't solve the problem in my compiler.  Good to know though.

Comment: @syplex You might not know the correct namespace (e.g., in template code or if using a typedef).

Comment: @Josh it seems incorrect to me for the compiler to just select a namespace when none was actually specified.  It weakens the concept of namespaces and scoping.  But I understand it has merits, I would be happy with the simple ability to disable it for a section of code or file.